# Akka actor cannot send self a PoisonPill

Tags: java, java-8, akka

Java/Akka here. I have the following actor:

```
public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public MyActor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Init.class, init -> {
                log.info("Sending myself a Poison Pill...");
                self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), self());
            }).match(PoisonPill.class, poisonPill -> {
                log.info("Got the Poison Pill...");
                context().system().terminate();
            }).build();
    }
}
```

When it receives an `Init` message, I see the following log statement written:

```
Sending myself a Poison Pill...
```

But I *never* see:

```
Got the Poison Pill...
```

Furthermore the app just sits there and does not shut down as expected. Is there something in my use of `self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), self())` which prevents it from receiving the message and shutting down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log message doesn't appear because [`PoisonPill`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/PoisonPill.html) is an [`AutoReceivedMessage`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.17/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L22). An `AutoReceivedMessage` is a special type of message that Akka handles internally and is not meant to be pattern-matched in user code.

One way to shut down the actor system once the actor is "poisoned"/stopped is to override the actor's `postStop()` method:

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
  return receiveBuilder()
    .match(Init.class, init -> {
      log.info("Sending myself a Poison Pill...");
      self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());
    })
    .build();
}

@Override
public void postStop() {
  getContext().getSystem().terminate();
}
```